# windows powershell command to uninstall all versions of java except a specific version

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Windows powershell command to uninstall all versions of Java except a specific version. This command should work in windows 7 & above.

The following command uninstalls all versions. How do I modify the following in such a way that a specific **version 8.0.770.3** does not uninstall.

```
gwmi Win32_Product -filter "name like 'Java%' AND vendor like 'Oracle%' AND (version like '[78].%' OR version like '1.[78].%')" | % { $_.Uninstall() }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the filtering of version.

```
gwmi Win32_Product -filter "name like 'Java%' AND vendor like 'Oracle%' AND
not version = '8.0.770.3'" | % { $_.Uninstall() }
```

Comment: Thanks much Martin! this did the trick..  can i run the same with command prompt ?. It would be very helpful if it works via cmd. 
powershell.exe "gwmi Win32_Product -filter "name like 'Java%' AND vendor like 'Oracle%' AND not version = '8.0.770.3'" | % { $_.Uninstall() }"

Comment: But you need to escape the `"`.. like this: `powershell.exe "gwmi Win32_Product -filter \"name like 'Java%' AND vendor like 'Oracle%' AND not version = '8.0.770.3'\" | % { $_.Uninstall() }"` .

Answer (score 0):

simplest powershell script

gwmi Win32_Product -filter "name like 'Java%'" | % { $_.Uninstall() }

Comment: Does this add value to [Martin's accepted 2016 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36199061)?